# Incompatible types in assignment on struct

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct s {
char name[20];
char last_name[20];
int height;
} s_t;

s_t my_s_t;
my_s_t.name = "John";
```

I get "Incompatible types in assignment" for the last line.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_s_t.name = "John";
```

`name` is a char array. So you can´t directly assign a string literal to it. You can use `strcpy` or similar function to copy the string literal OR declare `name` as `char*`.

Options:

1)

```
typedef struct s {
char name[20];
char last_name[20];
int height;
} s_t;

s_t my_s_t;
strcpy(my_s_t.name, "John");
```

2)

```
 typedef struct s {
    char *name;
    char last_name[20];
    int height;
    } s_t;

    s_t my_s_t;
    my_s_t.name = "John";
```

Comment: @Lior Because that's an initialisation, not an assignment. There are special rules that make initialisations work for arrays.

Comment: @Lior you can only do that when initializing the string. It will initialize the string literal on the stack.

Comment: It's also worth noting the usage of `strncpy` to not overflow

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to *assign* an array. Arrays are not assignable. This will fail for the same reason

```
char a[20];
a = "Hello"; /* Error */
```

In order to copy data into an array, you have to use a library function, like `strcpy`

```
strcpy(a, "Hello");
```

Meanwhile, it is possible to copy data into an array using core language features (instead of library functions) at the point of *initialization*, as in

```
char a[20] = "Hello";
```

In your case you can use aggregate initialization syntax to achieve the same

```
s_t my_s_t = { "John", "Smith", 2 };
```

As long as you are doing this at the point of initialization, it will work. If you have to do it later, then `strcpy` is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will accept @KingsIndian's since he was first :)